# How to auto-create the sprite and move them vertically in the room? GameMaker developer

Tags: game-maker, gml

Guys I want to do this without GML I guess it's[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9tqd.png) easy to do it.
You can see in the image I have uploaded. there are three sprites and I want them to enter the room randomly at specific location.

Guys I'm new to game maker this is my first game.

I'm making a shooting game for Android. You can refer the image for clear idea about the game.
Things I did are: I made 3 sprite red, yellow, green

What I want to do is:
I want the red yellow green sprite moving in vertically and the player gonna shoot them.

I want the sprite to get created automatically at random location(at the top I mean) and move in vertical direction and should not overlap each other.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a lot of different way to do this. The simplest one is to create an object, assign it a sprite, spawn it at a random y and assign it a vspeed.

in the object create event :

```
sprite_index = your_sprite;
x = 0;
y = random(room_width);
vspeed = the_speed_you_want;
```

I suppose you want to be able to shoot at the sprites, so it is better to make an object than to simply draw them.
If you don't want them to overlap, you can define 3 possible starting positions and randomly chose one with the choose() function.